# Why can I not cast IDbTransaction in ServiceStack OrmLite to DbTransaction?

Tags: c#, sqlite, ormlite-servicestack

I am using `ServiceStack.Ormlite v3.9.71` and have the following piece of code where I open an Ormlite SQLite Transaction, suppose I want to use this transaction in a command elsewhere in the code:

```
var connFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("ConnectionString", SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance)
using (IDbConnection db = connFactory.Open()) // using var doesn't make a difference
using (IDbTransaction tran = db.OpenTransaction()) // using var or even db.BeginTransaction() doesn't make a difference
{
    // I do lots of boring stuff
    ...

    // Somewhere else in the code
    using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tran; // get an error
    }
}
```

however when I do, I get the:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteTransaction' to type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction'.
```

And the Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.set_Transaction(IDbTransaction value)
```

I guess this is due to the OrmLiteTransaction wrapper, how can I get to the transaction?

Comment: What type is `db` and which connection factory are you using? (ie OpenTransaction isn't part of the normal IDbConnection interface)

Comment: Which version of OrmLite are you using? What is the type of `tmpTran` ? Where is it created?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, Added/Updated, my last update messed up the code

Comment: try changing using `using(IDbConnection db = connFactory.Open())` to `using (var db = connFactory.Open())` same for the next row. Perhaps not working with the interface has a version of `CreateCommand` that retruns a command that can accept a `OrmLiteTransaction`

Comment: @Mangus not sure about this. OrmLiteTransaction implements IDbTransaction but `cmd.Transaction` seems to expect a `DbCommand` *even though*  its type is IDbTransaction. Internally, SS uses `Mono.Data.Sqlite`. Could be that this driver uses DbTransaction?

Comment: @MaYaN What is the full call stack of the exception? Could it be that the exception occur inside OrmLite instead of your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OrmLite provides ToDbTransaction extension method.

```
public static IDbTransaction ToDbTransaction(this IDbTransaction dbTrans)
    {
        var hasDbTrans = dbTrans as IHasDbTransaction;
        return hasDbTrans != null
            ? hasDbTrans.Transaction
            : dbTrans;
    }
```

You can use it in your code like this.

```
cmd.Transaction = tran.ToDbTransaction()
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

OrmLiteConnection will return a SqliteCommand which means that it just isn't possible to set the command's Transaction property, because the command expects a SqliteTransaction object. Even if you try to set IDbCommand.Transaction, you'll call the `DbCommand.Transaction` setter which checks that the object passed *is* a DbTransaction object

The fix is to simply not set the Transaction property, as `db.CreateCommand` sets it itself if a transaction was already opened with `db.OpenTransaction`

**Original**

I think you should follow @Mangus' advice and use `var` instead of casting to interfaces.

Checking [SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite/SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.cs)'s implementation, it appears it's using Mono.Data.Sqlite. Mono.Data.Sqlite classes inherit from the abstract `DbXXX` classes but *hide* the base implementations with their own.

[SQLiteCommand.Transaction](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteCommand.cs) and [SQLiteConnection.CreateCommand](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/effa4c07ba850bedbe1ff54b2a5df281c058ebcb/mcs/class/Mono.Data.Sqlite/Mono.Data.Sqlite_2.0/SQLiteConnection.cs) have the following signatures:

```
public new SqliteCommand CreateCommand()
{
...
}

public new SqliteTransaction Transaction
{
...
}
```

By casting to the interfaces you call the *base* implementation in the DbConnection, DbCommand classes instead of the new implementations in Mono.Data.Sqlite. This means that `OpenTransaction` will return a `DbTransaction`-derived object instead of an OrmLiteTransaction object.

The following code should work:

```
var connFactory = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("ConnectionString", SqliteOrmLiteDialectProvider.Instance)
using (var db = connFactory.Open())
using (var tran = db.OpenTransaction()) // or even db.BeginTransaction()
{
    // I do lots of boring stuff
    ...

    // Somewhere else in the code
    using (var cmd = db.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.Transaction = tran; 
    }
}
```

ADO.NET providers since .NET 2.0 are expected to derive from the `DbXXX` abstract classes instead of implementing the .NET 1.1 interfaces like `IDbConnection`.

In your case, OrmLite breaks the expected behaviour resulting in a clash with Mono.Data.Sqlite's unexpected member hiding. Otherwise you wouldn't have noticed anything.

Comment: Nope it does not work, my original post did have the `var` keyword but I removed that for clarity, I get the exact same exception.

Comment: Don't set the property at all. `CreateCommand` sets the Transaction property if a transaction is already opened. You just can't pass an OrmLiteTransaction to the SqliteCommand. The original transaction is wrapped inside OrmLiteTransaction as a private field, so you can't use it either