# ServiceStack Ormlite transactions broken?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, ormlite-servicestack

I am using ServiceStack.Ormlite for SQL Server and just updated from 3.9.71 to 4.0.33.0 and now transactions for direct commands are failing. I can get ORMlite transactions working or direct commands, but not both.

The complication is I am doing some very complicated DB commands and since Sql.In() for a large list of GUIDs is massively slow I have a workaround which uses db.CreateCommand() and then passes the GUID list in as a custom table type.

Thus I need a single transaction to span across ORMLite commands and direct db commands. The following code used to work and now it fails.

For instance the following code used to work. I now get errors saying that the CreateCommand() should use the transaction. When I directly try then I get the indicated [cast exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234765/why-can-i-not-cast-idbtransaction-in-servicestack-ormlite-to-dbtransaction):

```
            using (var db = DB.Connection.OpenDbConnection())
            {
                using (var transaction = db.OpenTransaction())
                {
                    // Some ORMLite code
                    db.Delete<SomeType>();

                    using (var command = db.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        // Direct DB command
                        command.CommandText = "Delete from SomeTable where ...";
                        command.Parameters.Add(GUIDList)

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Clarification:**
In the code OpenTransaction() will work for the OrmLite code, but fail on the CreateCommand code. BeginTransaction() will fail for the OrmLite code.

The actual error is at command.ExecuteNonQuery(): ExecuteNonQuery requires the command to have a transaction when the connection assigned to the command is in a pending local transaction.  The Transaction property of the command has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [Transactions in OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#transaction-support) you should use the `OpenTransaction()` API, e.g:

```
using (var trans = db.OpenTransaction()) 
{
    //...
}
```

I've added a couple new API's to be able to use an OrmLite transaction with a raw ADO.NET `IDbCommand` [in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/a91e87644454eee2d7e1fb7287a66839ae901848).

#### Use a managed OrmLite DB Command

Use a managed OrmLite command with `OpenCommand()` which will automatically prepopulate the DB command with the current transaction, e.g:

```
using (var trans = db.OpenTransaction()) 
using (var command = db.OpenCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "Delete from SomeTable where ...";
}
```

#### Manually assign underlying DB Transaction

When using the underlying ADO.NET `IDbCommand` you will need to also manually assign the Transaction to the command yourself, i.e:

```
using (var trans = db.OpenTransaction()) 
using (var command = db.CreateCommand())
{
    command.Transaction = trans.ToDbTransaction();
    command.CommandText = "Delete from SomeTable where ...";
}
```

The `ToDbTransaction()` extension method lets you access the underlying ADO.NET `IDbTransaction` which is required when using the underlying ADO.NET `IDbCommand`.

Both of these new API's are available from **v4.0.34+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: I added a clarification. The code I use actualy does use OpenTransaction which works for OrmLite, but fails on the ADO.Net code. BeginTransaction will fail for OrmLite, but work for the ADO.net code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion that works.It is based on previous answers

```
IDbConnection conn = DB.Connection;
IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
using (IDbTransaction transaction = conn.OpenTransaction())
{
    //ADO.NET code
    cmd.Transaction = transaction.ToDbTransaction();
    cmd.CommandText = "...Some sql text";
    cmd.executeNonQuery();
    // Some ORMLite code
    conn.Delete<SomeType>();
}
```